# CSS blur ignoring z-index

Tags: css, z-index, blur

Fella's!
I'm trying to create the same effect as the iphone search bar on the homescreen.

When you click on the body of my page, a bar will appear and the rest of the page will become blurry. Now there is a problem, The white bar on the top should have a hard border but on the bottom the blur of the .page gets over it. I tried to change the z-indexes but it seems that there is not the solution.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7bm8qssb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blur effect is bleeding into the header div. Give your `.page` section `overflow: hidden;` to avoid this.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bm8qssb/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Do you have any idea why this solution not works for FF?

Comment: You may have to wrap the element with the blur inside of another div for the overflow to be hidden. Here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bm8qssb/3/.

Answer (score 0):

Just add simple line in `.page` to avoid outside blur effect:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bm8qssb/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think about that!

Comment: Do you have any idea why this solution not works for FF?